# Cambiar color a input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un `input text` con un background transparente y lo que quiero hacer es que cambie su background  al posicionarme en el, algo así como se ve en la imagen pero con `JQuery` o `JS` [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos que has intentado hasta el momento para poder tener una plantilla para ayudarte.

Comment: Debes mostrar el código que has intentado usar para poderte ayudar, recuerda leer [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con CSS sin necesidad de usar Javascript como muestro a continuación:

```
Input:Focus {
     Background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Muy bien, lo intenté ya y funciono

Answer (score 5):

Espero esto sea lo que buscas

En este caso usamos `jquery` al activar el evento `focus` que al elemento se le cambie la propiedad `background` y al activar el evento `blur` que vuelva a su estatus anterior.

```js
$(".input").focus(function(){
  $(this).css({"background":"rgb(82, 179, 126)"})
})
$(".input").blur(function(){
  $(this).css({"background":"transparent"})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="background con jquery" class="input" type="text" name="" value="">
```

En este caso solo hay que usar la propiedad de `css` `:focus` que se activa cuando el `input` esta activo

```css
input:focus {
  background: rgb(168, 168, 168);
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="input cambio de color" type="text" name="" value="">
```

Comment: De hecho el hover, lo tengo con Js y quería que al darle click se cambiara al color del hover pero con el Focus en CSS me funcionó bien y lo dejaré así por ahora si me sirvió tu primer respuesta

Comment: excelente especifica un poquito mas para poder darte la solución acorde al caso saludos

Comment: listo ya lo acomode a tu caso espero ahora si te ayude! y recuerda especificar un poco mejor que es lo que necesitas

Comment: Claro, y si ya quedó bien!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizarlo con JavaScript con estilos:

```js
function Color(ele){
  if ($(ele).val() === "") {
    $(ele).css("background-color", "");
  }
  else{
    $(ele).css("background-color", "pink");
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="ejemplo" name="ejemplo"  onchange="Color(this)"/>
</body>
```